# .NET CLR specifications

Tags: .net, clr, specifications

Where can I find the spec of CLR ?
For example, I want to look at how is implemented in memory the object "ThreadStart".

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest I'm aware of is [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) which is the CLI specification. However, you should be aware that the ECMA memory model is significantly weaker than the .NET one. (Where .NET is Microsoft's implementation of the CLI.)

I doubt that the CLI specifically mentions `ThreadStart` though - it's just another delegate. What are you particularly interested in about it?

Comment: I would like to see how is built an object like delegate in memory (its fields, methods, etc...).

Comment: Well you *can* look at that with Reflector, but that will be implementation-specific - I wouldn't expect to find that information in a specification. You should also bear in mind that delegates have a sort of dual nature - you can view them in a multicast way, or you can consider what one "action" would have. You can see this in the Delegate.Method/Target properties and the MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList method.

Comment: CLI specifications drive only C# language or the CLR  implementation also? Is the ECMA specification for CLR different from ECMA-335? Let's say I've to write a CLR implementation for a different OS other than windows then which ECMA specification I should be following?

Comment: @RBT: The CLI specifications are more to do with the CLR than with C#. There's no specification for the CLR - the CLR is *an* implementation of the CLI (as I understand it; it's a bit confusing). But yes, if you wanted to write another runtime, ECMA 335 if what you'd use.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the Spec but if you want to look at implementation details you may want to use [Red-gate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Answer (score 2):

is [the common language infrastructure specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569283.aspx) what you are looking for?

The page contains many links to things like the [c# language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) and the [CLI](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf)